# Linux Bash, multiple MYSQL commands

Tags: mysql, bash

I am trying to figure out how to format a multiple variable request to mysql in a bash script.  I have 5 variables to be set in my bash script.  Each variable is retrived from a remote DB.  I currently have each variable on a separate line with its own separate login.

```
chatTo=$(mysql -D DB -u user -p'password' -h "$Control" -P 3309 -se "SELECT value FROM configuration WHERE label='chatTo'")

chatFrom=$(mysql -D DB -u user -p'password' -h "$Control" -P 3309 -se "SELECT value FROM configuration WHERE label='chatFrom'")
```

I am quite sure that there is a more efficient way to do this. I am trying:

```
mysql -D DB -u user -p'password' -h "$Control" -P 3309 -se << END
    chatFrom=$(SELECT value FROM configuration WHERE label='chatFrom');
    chatTo=$(SELECT value FROM configuration WHERE label='chatTo');
    END
```

This is not working.  I imagine it is a formating issue.  Or can I even assign multiple variables like this? Seems to me that limiting the login logout processes is more secure.

Comment: `END` is not causing your problem (I'm certain). Although your indenting of the closing `END` may not be helping things. BUT your 2nd block of code has shell command-substitution syntax embedded (i.e. `$( cmd ...)` ). This will never work. You'll need to find out correct mysql syntax to create a local variable in the SQL query space, and then how to assigned a value from a query to those variables. Good luck.

Comment: To separate the output from a single program run into multiple variables, you need some characteristic to decide where one part ends and the other part begins. If you showed sample output, one could offer an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `EOF` instead of `END`

Example:

```
mysql -uroot -proot SOMEDATABASE << EOF
insert into TABLENAME (name,lastname,address,telephone) values $_name , '$_lastname', '$_address' , '$_tel';
EOF
```

As for your code, just use `;` in the end of each line:

```
mysql -uroot -proot SOMEDATABASE << EOF
SELECT value FROM configuration WHERE label='chatTo';
SELECT value FROM configuration WHERE label='chatFrom';
EOF
```

Comment: that can't be right.  The variable must be assigned in order to use later in the script.

Comment: @Cybergei  Well in that case you should run it one by one.